# Use JavaScript to cut the GET part of the url including the?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, include

I am trying a lot of things out now a days but some things are making me stumped like using ajax to include a file that handles the the GET requests of the parent file. So instead of say including `file.php` I would include `file.php?all_gets=all&from=the_parent_file`

The parent file calls out `file.php` with ajax, it works but when I ask it to `var_dump($_GET)` it will display as array 0 even though the parent frame has a `$_GET` in it.  Now when I try including `file.php?get=somegetvar` and then I `var_dump()` it, it gives me the $_GET for the included page. My issue is now how to use this to transfer the `$_GET` from the parent file (that includes `file.php`) using JS to the include file so "file.php"+gets

Is this possible? I am really stumped on this - this could be my solution...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post some code and explain how you're request/include is supposed to work?

Comment: It's not quite clear exactly what you want to do, please explain further.

Comment: right, ill do that if none of these answers work.

Comment: It's still rather vague, what is your ultimate goal? to pass your GET variables from one request to an ajax call? Check the answer I just added if so, otherwise we need more context.

Comment: @Mahn, yes basically, maybe its unclear as this is my first time using Ajax... anyway, I appreciate all your help.

Comment: I think next time you should try to work a bit more on understanding your own question before asking it; don't take it personally, just a neutral tip.

Comment: @Mahn lol, no i don't take it personally but i do understand my question enough to have answers that work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check with

window.location.href : will return whole url including parameters

window.location.search : will return only parameters

Comment: Ok, I will try yours out as it seems the most reasonable to fit to my requirements :D.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<script>
    var getVars = JSON.parse("<?= json_encode($_GET) ?>");

    $.ajax({
        url: "",
        data: getVars,
        //[...]
    });

</script>
```

Comment: hmm... I guess but sorry, Loken got here first. Anyway, u still got an up vote :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but just going off the title you can use this:

```
str = str.replace(/\?.+/, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following jquery plugins:

- **https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser** (recommended)
- http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-urlinternal-plugin/
- http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

They are url manipulating libraries